# ASP.Net Web Project Using Default Login.aspx

Tags: asp.net, login-control

Created a ASP.Net Web Application.
Wanted to make use of Default Login / Registration that comes in the account folder.
From what I have read it appears that this suited to getting anonymous users to register.

I need to restrict access based on a preknown set of users held in a database table.

Is this a good fit with the above  or should I just stick with my usual practice of writing the login logic on my default page.

If it is a good fit is there a step 1,2,3 guide to using it? e.g. Mention is made of a database needed in Accounts but is there a default schema for it somewhere?

The majority of web projects that I work on are of this 'restricted user' nature so if the canned login / registration is not a good fit then I can just keep rolling my own.

Answer (score 1):

> From what I have read it appears that this suited to getting anonymous
>   users to register. I need to restrict access based on a preknown set
>   of users held in a database table.

This is not correct. Every user is anonymous before he registers unless we are running a face recognition algorithm. Every registration page should allow anonymous users unless it is an intranet application which disallows login from outside IPs.

ASP.NET has a powerful Membership module with Role based Site navigation enabled. The learning curve is very low. Try that.

Useful Links

1. http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security (28 tutorials on ASP.NET membership, roles and managing them)
2. http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/authentication (20 video tutorials on the same topic if you prefer video more)